# How to increase swap size in gparted

Tags: ubuntu, swap

I have the system with 4GB RAM and 300 GB HDD.
I think 123 MB is not enough for the swap partition.

1. Which swap size should I choose?
2. How can I increase it in `gparted`?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBXRw.jpg

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

1. Recommended minimum swap size for the system with 4GB RAM is 2GB without hibernation and 6GB with hibernation.
   Recommended maximum swap size is 8GB cause of diminishing returns.
2. You could delete `extended` partition (cause it is unnecessary), resize `root` partition and create new `swap` partition (cause you can not resize it only create new one. but if you can do it, you are a very lucky one).

## Long answer

1. According to [SwapFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_much_swap_do_I_need.3F):

> For more modern systems (>1GB), your swap space should be at a minimum be equal to your physical memory (RAM) size "if you use hibernation", otherwise you need a minimum of `round(sqrt(RAM))` and a maximum of twice the amount of RAM. The only downside to having more swap space than you will actually use, is the disk space you will be reserving for it.
>
> ```
>         RAM   No hibernation    With Hibernation  Maximum
>       256MB            256MB               512MB    512MB
>       512MB            512MB              1024MB   1024MB
>      1024MB           1024MB              2048MB   2048MB
>
>            RAM   No hibernation    With Hibernation  Maximum
>            1GB              1GB                 2GB      2GB
>            2GB              1GB                 3GB      4GB
>            3GB              2GB                 5GB      6GB
>            4GB              2GB                 6GB      8GB
>            5GB              2GB                 7GB     10GB
>            6GB              2GB                 8GB     12GB
>            8GB              3GB                11GB     16GB
>           12GB              3GB                15GB     24GB
>           16GB              4GB                20GB     32GB
>           24GB              5GB                29GB     48GB
>           32GB              6GB                38GB     64GB
>           64GB              8GB                72GB    128GB
>          128GB             11GB               139GB    256GB
>          256GB             16GB               272GB    512GB
>          512GB             23GB               535GB      1TB
>            1TB             32GB              1056GB      2TB
>            2TB             46GB              2094GB      4TB
>            4TB             64GB              4160GB      8TB
>            8TB             91GB              8283GB     16TB
> ```

2. You could boot the system with a [bootable Ubuntu USB stick](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu), launch `Gparted` and do things as described in [SwapFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_or_modify_a_swap_partition.3F) (also you could see [this beautiful answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/389067/463242)):

> Creating the swap partition
>
> 1. Boot to Ubuntu install CD and choose the option to run Ubuntu now
> 2. Go to `system -> GParted Partition Editor`
> 3. Delete the swap partition and, if there is nothing else in it, the extended partition that holds it. (If by some miracle you're able to resize your swap partition from here, I imagine your life will be a lot easier than mine.)
> 4. Decrease the size of your primary partition by the amount you want your new swap to be (I made mine 2x RAM + 500MB just to be safe). The easiest way to do this is to fill in the amount of space you want swap to be in the "free space following" field
> 5. In the free space that has now been created, choose new, type linux-swap and you can name the partition "swap" if you like
> 6. Hit the *Apply* button (should be a check mark) to write the changes to disk
> 7. When done, `reboot` back into Ubuntu
>
> ---
>
> Activating the `swap` partition
> *(If your `swap` is on your primary hard drive, you don't need to do anything here.)*
> Now you need to find what partition your `swap` is on and what its UUID is. UUID?! you say? Well that's the Universally Unique IDentifier for the partition so you can reference it even if it's on a different mount point from boot-to-boot due to adding disks, etc.
>
> 1. Pull up a terminal and run `gksu gparted &` and enter your root password. The `&` lets this process run while still giving you access to the command line.
> 2. Right-click on your `swap` partition and choose *Information*. You should see the **Path** and **UUID** listed there. Keep this open for further reference.
> 3. Run `gksu gedit /etc/fstab &` and look for the line that has *swap* in it. It should be the third column, separated by spaces or tabs. You can either use the path or the UUID to tell Linux where to find your swap partition. I recommend UUID because it'll stay constant even if you move the partition around or the disk somehow becomes sdb instead of sda or something like that. Make the appropriate edits and save the file. Your line should look something like this if you used UUID (with your UUID instead, of course):
>
> ```
> UUID=41e86209-3802-424b-9a9d-d7683142dab7 none swap sw 0 0
> ```
>
> or if you used `path`:
>
> ```
> /dev/sda2 none swap sw 0 0
> ```
>
> 4. Save the `file`.
> 5. Enable the new `swap` partition with this command.
>
> ```
> sudo swapon --all
> ```

OR

> ```
> $ sudo swapon --all --verbose
> swapon on /dev/sda2
> swapon: /dev/sda2: found swap signature: version 1, page-size 4, same byte order
> swapon: /dev/sda2: pagesize=4096, swapsize=2147483648, devsize=2147483648
> ```
>
> 6. Confirm that the `swap` partition exists:
>
>    ```
>      $ cat /proc/swaps
>      Filename       Type            Size    Used    Priority
>      /dev/sda2      partition       2097148 0       -1
>    ```
> 7. Reboot to make sure the new swap gets activated properly at startup